# css grid header with content and sidebar with max width and centre

Tags: html, css

I am having a breakdown trying to make this work, I have a layout that I now want to make responsive, I need the content to get smaller when the browser is resized but need the sidebar to be a fixed 300px and the site to be in the center with a max width of 960px

so far

```
.container{
display: grid;
grid-gap: 20px;
grid-template-areas: 
"header  header"
"sidebar content";
grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

#header {
grid-area: header;
height: 96px;
}

#mainbar{
grid-area: content;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-right: 20px;
 }

#sidebar{
grid-area: sidebar;
margin: 0;
margin: 0 0 15px 0
}
```

never got round to making the sidebar a fixed 300px width as was just trying to get it to work at any widths

```
 <div class="container">
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="mainbar"></div>
 <div id="sidebar"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing quotations on the end of `container`. You're also missing a semi-colon on `sidebar's` `margin`. Sidebar also doesn't show up because it doesn't have a height or width.

Check out [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/nick_kinlen/pen/WNvYGNN). I fixed the typos and gave `Sidebar` a height and width, it's responsive.

If you want to add different styles depending on the width of the screen (i.e. stacking elements on mobile view) look into using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: great ty thats perfect, any change you know how to make this whole thing 960wide max and in the center of screen which will then get smaller if screen width is less than the 960

Comment: I added a `max-width: 960px` and `margin: 0 auto` to the example.